# rspec files missing end but throws error when I have it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an rspec file and it looks like it is missing two "ends" but when I put those ends on, my tests throw an error "unexpected end"...here's the file:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe Invoice do

  describe 'creation' do

    before(:each) do
      @invoice = FactoryGirl.build(:invoice)
    end

    it 'is invalid without a user'  do
      invoice = @invoice
      invoice.user = nil
      invoice.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid without a client'  do
      invoice = @invoice
      invoice.client = nil
      invoice.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid without a public_id'  do
      invoice = @invoice
      invoice.public_id = nil
      invoice.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid without a payment_term'  do
      invoice = @invoice
      invoice.payment_term = nil
      invoice.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid without an issue_date'  do
      invoice = @invoice
      invoice.issue_date = nil
      invoice.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid without a client_invoice_id'  do
      invoice = @invoice
      invoice.client_invoice_id = nil
      invoice.should_not be_valid
    end
  end

  describe 'method has_payment_date?' do

    it "should return true when payment_term is not 'None'"
      @invoice = FactoryGirl.build(:invoice)
      @invoice.payment_term = "Net 15"
      @invoice.has_payment_date?.should == true
    end

    it "should return false when payment_term is 'None'"
      @invoice = FactoryGirl.build(:invoice)
      @invoice.payment_term = "Net 15"
      @invoice.has_payment_date?.should == true
    end
```

now it seems that the above code is missing two "end"s but it passes when it's like this and throws an error when i put the ends back. what am i missing?

Comment: you are missing the ending `do` on your last two `it`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing both two "do" in last two examples and two "end" in "Invoice" and "method has_payment_date?" describes.